# VB6 listbox sorting differently in different operating systems

Tags: sorting, vb6

I am working on an VB6 application where some of my customers use the old version and some of my customers use the new version.

In the new version, there is a listbox populated with subfolders of a directory using the FileSystemObject and a For Each loop:

```
Dim objFileSys As New FileSystemObject
Dim myFolder as Folder
Set myFolder = objFileSys.GetFolder(Path)
For Each mysubfolder In myFolder.SubFolders
    listbox1.AddItem mysubfolder.Name
Next
```

In the old version, the Dir$ function is used:

```
Dim DirName As String
DirName = Dir$(Path, ATTR_DIRECTORY)
Do While DirName <> ""
  If DirName <> "." And DirName <> ".." Then
    If (GetAttr(Path & DirName) And ATTR_DIRECTORY) = ATTR_DIRECTORY Then
      listbox1.AddItem DirName
    End If
  End If
  DirName = Dir$
Loop
```

In the old version, the listbox1.sort property is true, and in the new version, the listbox1.sort property is false.  There is no code that performs any sorting whatsoever.

Here is where it gets weird.  When I run the applications in Windows 10, the list box is sorted correctly in both versions.  When I run the application in Windows 7, the old version (the one with listbox.sort=true) is not sorting correctly, but the new version (the one with the listbox.sort=false) is sorting correctly.

What could be causing this to happen?

Comment: What does *sorting incorrectly* mean?

Comment: It is not sorting alphanumerically.  The sorting seems to be totally random.

Comment: Show examples of the sort.

Comment: Is 'sorting randomly' different from 'not sorting'?

Comment: I need the sorting to be alphanumeric for all versions and all operating systems.  I am not at a location where I have access to the examples.  All the subfolders start with BCH followed by a 5 digit number.

Comment: I would think that both methods and both operating systems would return a list in alphabetical order regardless.  It's been a long time (think DOS) since directories did NOT sort alphabetically automatically.  In MS-DOS days, you had to use a utility like Norton Utilities to sort your directories, but those days are long gone, I thought.  Debug.Print each directory before you .addItem in the listbox and see if they're going into the box in order in the first place.

Comment: The development environment is a WinXP Virtual Box.  Do not have access to the users' machines to be able to use debug.print.  I agree with you that this is very strange.  I am an old DOS guy.

Comment: Alternatively, you could simply build (concatenate) a string using the list items separated by vbNewLine (I think that's the constant - or vbCrLf) and then look at it via msgbox.

Comment: I believe I may have found the problem.  It has to do with the different ways that FAT32 and NTFS store their file lists.  See this link: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/481570/default-file-order-of-dir-command-in-windows-console).  I believe the solution can be found here: [link](https://superuser.com/questions/315003/change-default-sorting-order-of-dir-command-in-windows).  I have submitted the suggestion to my customers and am waiting for a response.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing the system variable as described in my previous comment made no difference .

Comment: Sometimes sort order is controlled by an interpretation of the locale of the text (something like a collating sequence in a database, for instance). Just a guess if that could be relevant. Maybe the random sort is actually sorting assuming a different locale or text encoding?

Answer (score 0):

This is likely down to the order the files are being returned by the file system API call in the operating system. It may also be down to the filesystem being used.

Many filesystems are not inherently sorted structures, but client software used to represent them obscures this fact by sorting e.g. file and folder lists.

e.g. a common problem with flash MP3 players was people copying music files to them and them playing out of order, because the firmware was just reading the files in the order they occurred in the file allocation table, and ignoring the filenames (even if they had `01 - track name` kind of names).

It sounds like one of the following is true

- The Windows 10 API sorts file names when it returns lists of them

  - Given the fervour that MS puts into backward compatibility, I'm not sure this is true, especially since all the user software has long since got used to unsorted lists
- Your Windows 10 system is newer, and the files were copied onto it fresh

  - This means the files are on the disk in the actual order they were copied, which is probably the sorted order
  - The Windows 7 box likely has had the files for some time and they're written on the disk in a non-sorted order
  - Therefore it's just good fortune that the "old" code works on Windows 10

So that may explain the "random" sort order.

---

Back to VB6 : the Sorted property of the VB6 ListBox control is what's called an "Action" property - setting it does something. The control doesn't sort lists while you are populating them. Populate the list THEN set the .Sorted property.

The new code is likely producing a sorted list because FileSystemObject behaves differently to `Dir$()` (ie, it probably sorts the files because this was a common frustration)

```
Dim DirName As String
DirName = Dir$(Path, ATTR_DIRECTORY)
Do While DirName  ""
  If DirName  "." And DirName  ".." Then
    If (GetAttr(Path & DirName) And ATTR_DIRECTORY) = ATTR_DIRECTORY Then
      listbox1.AddItem DirName
    End If
  End If
  DirName = Dir$
Loop
listbox1.Sorted = True ' After the loop
```

Comment: There is no problem whatsoever with users on Windows 10 machines.  The problem is with all users on Windows 7 machines.  And all are reading the directory listing located on a Windows Server 2012.  And this was working fine until a recent update on either the Windows 7 machines or server.